# Back Substitution Method for solving recursive equation

Tags: recursion

Does back substitution method work for any recursive equation? If not is there any generalized form for recursive equation?

Comment: Back substitution doesn't always work. There is no general method which is always guaranteed to hold. Such is math.

Comment: Back substitution doesn't seem to help for the Fibonacci recurrence $F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2)$, for example.

Comment: We have a [reference question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2789/solving-or-approximating-recurrence-relations-for-sequences-of-numbers) on the topic of solving recurrence relations.